# 'Signed JWT rejected' when spring resource server is restarted

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-authorization-server, spring-resource-server

I am getting "Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found" in spring resource server when I restart Spring resource server.

Error is coming from DefaultJwtProcessor

```
JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = extractJWTClaimsSet(signedJWT);

        List<? extends Key> keyCandidates = selectKeys(signedJWT.getHeader(), claimsSet, context);

        if (keyCandidates == null || keyCandidates.isEmpty()) {
            throw new BadJOSEException("Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found");
        }
```

I followed the sample provided in spring authorization server.

How can I fix this issue?

```
Spring authorization server

@Bean
    @Lazy
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        final RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        final JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);

        return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
    }

public static RSAKey generateRsa() {
            final KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
            final RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
            final RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
            // @formatter:off
            return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
            // @formatter:on
        }

static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;

        try {
            final KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }
```

```
Spring resource server

private JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(final String issuerUri) {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withIssuerLocation(issuerUri).jwsAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The keys in the [Getting Started example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#defining-required-components) are generated at startup time. You can try loading keys from a persistent location, such as a file ([example](https://github.com/sjohnr/sas-native-demo/blob/929e543c0646dcf4663ec070d2e91bb0d56e462a/src/main/java/com/example/SecurityConfig.java#L56-L78)) or database ([example](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-enterprise-authorization-server/blob/main/authorization-server/src/main/java/com/example/authorizationserver/RsaKeyPairRepositoryJWKSource.java)).